# Type of lights needed for desert terrarium

Tags: indoors, succulents

What type of lighting would work best for a desert/drought plant set up in an 8x8x8 terrarium without a top?

Comment: eight inches, right? Not centimeters or feet?

Comment: There is no such thing as a desert terrarium; they are polar opposites. Cactus/succulents grown in closed containers can be tricky. They generally don't like wet feet or high humidity (this isn't universally true, but it's a reliable rule of thumb). As far as lights go, the brightest possible as close to the plants as possible. Keep in mind desert plants normally get extremely high levels of solar radiation which is hard to replicate indoors.